# Getting a 415 Unsupported Media Type error when posting an ASP.NET Core MVC form with unobtrusive ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, unobtrusive-ajax

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC Core web application. I have a form in my View that posts to the Create action in the ProductsController. I am using jquery unobtrusive ajax so my form looks like the following:

```
<form asp-action="Create" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-success="onSuccess"></form>
```

**Here is what my Create action looks like:**

```
[HttpPost("Products/Create")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create([Bind("Id,Name")] ProductViewModel vm)
{
}
```

This works completely fine.

**However, the following does not:**

```
[HttpPost("Products/Create")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] ProductViewModel vm)
{
}
```

I get an error in the js console: 415 (Unsupported Media Type). I am assuming this is because when the form is posted it isn't being set w/ Content-Type application/json.

It seems like Microsoft uses the Bind syntax when using their MVCController template and they use the FromBody syntax when using their APIController template.

I rarely use MVC for what it is these days since most of my pages involve ajax. I believe I am better treating my Action Methods more like API calls rather than MVC actions which is why I am trying to use FromBody.

Also, when I post to the FromBody Create action in Postman as Json with content-type application/json it works perfectly.

Comment: Not clear why you want to use the `[FromBody]` option, but get rid of the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file and just use `$.ajax()` to post (and then you can set the `contentType` (and in the first example, remove the `[Bind]` attribute - your never use that when using a view model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I was thinking to just do away with unobtrusive ajax and do a standard ajax post. It will save me aggravation. Would you recommend just adding an Id to the form and using jquery form submit? Also, are you saying I shouldn't use Bind or FromBody? What if this is just a standard API shouldnt I be using [FromBody] viewModel

Comment: You don't necessarily need a `id` attribute for the form - just can just use `$('form').submit(function() { $.ajax(.....); return false; })`. And I mean you do not need the `[Bind("Id,Name")]` attribute in your first example - your using a view model so your already protected against over-posting attacks. And `[FromBody]` is not required either since its the default (you would only need that if the parameter was a primitive type or string)

Comment: @StephenMuecke One last question that you might be able to answer. If the api accepts a post formatted as json then how would I send the data in the ajax request? I have tried doing data: $(this).serialize() and JSON.stringify($(this).serialize()); neither are working

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify($('form').serialize()),` will work if you set `contentType: 'application/json'` (note that is you were using `$.ajax()` as opposed to say `$.post()`, then `$(this)` would be the ajax function, not the form

Comment: @StephenMuecke since I am using $("form").submit(function (event) with ajax inside of it, I believe 'this' ends up being the form. Also unless I specify [FromBody] the ViewModel is not populated when contentType=application/json. I am so close to getting this, the final thing I need to do is go from the form to a javascript object w/ key value pairs, then finally a json string. JSON.stringify($('form').serialize()) is not working. $('form').serialize() alone creates a string that looks like this "Name=testName&CategoryId=5&AnotherProperty=Testing"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130872/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-blake-rivell).